# What is the correct way to take screenshot for the Mac App Store Submission?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, screen-capture

I want to submit my app to the mac app store. Mac App Store is asking for the screenshot of the dimensions 1280x800, 1440x900, 2880x1800 or 2560x1600. My samsung display does not support this dimensions. If I take the screenshot using Grab and scale it to the 1280x800 dimension it is not looking great. What is the correct way to take the screen for the MAS submission?

PS: My Samsung Supported dimensions:
640x480,720x576,800x600,1024x576,1024x768,1280x960,1344x756,1344x1008,1600x900

Answer (score 5):

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2) — in the last row of the table it says:

> One screenshot is required for Mac apps.
>   Up to four additional screenshots can be uploaded. Screenshots appear on the store in the order they were uploaded in iTunes Connect.
>   Screenshot requirements are:
>
> - 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format in the RGB color space
> - 16:10 aspect ratio
> - One of the following sizes:
>
>   - 1280 x 800 pixels
>   - 1440 x 900 pixels
>   - 2880 x 1800 pixels

Comment: The question is how to make screenshot if the display does not support any of the required sizes, not what the required sizes are.

Comment: I took this to be a correction of the implied idea that one had to upload every possible resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Cocoa stores the frame size of the last window using `NSUserDefaults`.

You can use this to set the window frame using Terminal:

1. Exit your application.
2. Run: `defaults write <your domain> "NSWindow Frame <YourWindowName>LastWindowFrame" "0 123 <frame width> <frame height> 0 0 2560 1600 "`.
3. Restart your application.

You can inspect the `<YourWindowName>` part using:

`defaults read <your domain>`

Comment: Fantastic answer. For others, the `<your domain>` is the Bundle Identifier shown in Xcode, .e.g. `com.yourcompany.yourapp`, at least for Catalyst apps.

Comment: On Big Sur, I still had to fiddle with the frame width/height. E.g. I  used 1328 788 to get screenshots actually sized 1440 x 900, when using shift-Cmd-4 <space> to capture them, but at least it became predictable.

Comment: This might be due to the window shadow being captured as well. I believe holding down Option while capturing prevents the window shadow from being included.

Comment: Note that I have to use `defaults write <your domain> "NSWindow Frame <YourWindowName>" "0 123 <frame width> <frame height> 0 0 2560 1600 "` (i.e., without the `LastWindowFrame`).

Answer (score 1):

I had with the same issue on my Apple Cinema Display.  It only supports 16:9 aspect ratios.

The simplest approach (that avoids image editing) is to use a Mac laptop with a 16:10 aspect ratio.  All I needed to do was unplug my MacBook Air from the Cinema Display, and then I got 16:10 ratios in Display System Preferences.  1440x900 and 1280x800 are both available.

[image: MacBook Air]

My MacBook Pro with Retina Display, natively supports 16:10 at 2880x1800.

Answer (score 0):

Press command + shift + 5 and drag the rectangle to have the necessary size. Then capture a screenshot. The size of the rectangle will use points, you need to multiply them by 2 typically when capturing on a Retina screen. For example, when it shows 1440 x 900, the screenshot will be 2022 x 1800.

Comment: 2 * 1440 is 2880 for me? Also, how does this help to capture a screenshot of an application window?

Comment: You capture window and background around it. You can drag the box to have any size.